# Additional themes

Tags: jquery-ui, themes, jquery-ui-theme

Are there any additional themes for jquery UI anywhere (jqueryui.com exluded)?

I've found the following theme:

- http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/482577430/introducing-aristo-a-jquery-ui-theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theme called 'Absolution' written by Michaël Vanderheeren, inspired by jQuery Mobile:

- http://www.michaelvanderheeren.be/?p=382

And Mike Stone has a link to his 'Hot Dog Stand' theme from his blog:

- http://smellsblue.blogspot.com/2009/04/jquery-ui-theme-tribute.html